# PassportJS not authenticate

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

What am I doing wrong? It always redirect to failure page but I cant debug.

```
// passport
var passport = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
    User = require('./models/user.js').Model;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
  },
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
      console.log('entrou');
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));


// login
app.get('/login', user.login);
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { 
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login' 
  })
);
```

Comment: How is findOne implemented ?

Comment: Also, do `err` and `user` contain expected values after logging in (`console.log` them)? Have you implemented `passport.serializeUser` and `passport.deserializeUser`, and all the other requirements for Passport?

Comment: I am having similar problem, debugging shows that (!user.validPassword) is returning false before the method inside sets it to true. (Almost like it was executing in an async method, but it is syncd right?) -- edit : I figured it out, bcrypt fires off an asynch method inside my auth function - so it evaluates false before it has the chance to evaluate the response from bcrypt.

Answer (score 2):

I had some issues too with passport.js not authenticating. So here it is how it works for me:

```
/**
 * Local authentication strategy
 *
 */
passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
  //async code waits until next()
  process.nextTick(function() {
    //searches the database for the user
    //that matches the username|e-mail and password provided
    models.User.checkCredentials(username, password, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }

      //user is not found
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown user ' + username});
      }

      return done(null, user);
    });
  });
}));
```

Log in a user

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    // if user is not found due to wrong username or password
    if (!user) {
      return res.render('login', {
        //you can send a message to your view
        message: 'Invalid username or password'
      });
    }
    //passport.js has a logIn user method
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }

      return res.redirect('/');
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```